# meaning of the term "Stateful" in programming

Tags: web-services

What does the term Stateful mean ?

I have heard my colleagues talk about stateful web services what does it mean that the service is stateful ?

And many says that stateless webservices means better performance and scalability why so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stateful web service is able to remember data between calls - typically using member variables, or what have you.

If you see methods like `getNextFoo`, `getCurrentBar` or similar, it's likely a stateful service. The opposite, a stateless service, is a service where the client needs to supply all information needed for the call - every time.

A stateful service is typically harder to develop and scale than stateless services. It requires the server to keep a state for the particular user session for some time. It's even harder to share that state among several servers as well (if you need more than one server). In the case of a server failover/restart, the client might not be affected if stateless services are used, but will likely have problems with a stateful service.

Comment: Hi what about persisting this state information to in memory database like oracle coherence or SQL Server in memory tables in 2014.

Comment: why is a stateful web service difficult to develop is it because of the server restarts so we need to write additional logic to persist the state in a permanent store like a db.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out and answering this on a sunday

Comment: You can obviously use SQL or whatever external mechanisms to store and retrieve "states". However, when I hear the word "stateless web service", I'm thinking about a state in the web service layer itself. Typically member variables in the implementing class. Pretty much all web services with write capabilities (stateless or statefull) changes some state elsewhere (Database or whatnot).